# Enable sshd logging in docker

Tags: docker, logging, containers, sshd

I managed to run a SFTP server on Openshift. However, I could not enable any logging for it. I would like to have logs for all login attempts, and uploading/downloading actions being taken.

I installed rsyslog. I also made changes on both `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/rsyslog.conf` as followings:

sshd_config

```
SyslogFacility LOCAL5
LogLevel VERBOSE
```

rsyslog.conf

```
local5.*  /var/log/sshd.log
```

However, sshd.log file was not found when I tried to do a `sftp` command connecting to localhost on docker terminal. How can I enable logging for this? Thanks.

This is my entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

USER_ID=$(id -u)
if [ ${USER_UID} != ${USER_ID} ]; then
sed "s@${USER_NAME}:x:\${USER_ID}:@${USER_NAME}:x:${USER_ID}:@g" /etc/passwd.template > /etc/passwd
fi

#while true; do echo 1; sleep 10; done

/usr/sbin/rsyslogd
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 32222

exec "$@"
```

This is how I build the image and container.

```
oc new-app oc new-app --strategy=docker --code=. --name <NameOfMyApp>
oc start-build --from-dir='.' --no-cache=true <NameOfMyApp>
```

Comment: You've installed it, but are you in fact running `rsyslogd` inside your container?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Seems like it is not running. `ps -A` did not show rsyslogd. However, I put `/usr/sbin/rsyslog` in my entrypoint.sh before kicking off the sshd. Any clue why it is not running?
`/usr/sbin/rsyslogd
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -p 32222`

Comment: What does your complete `entrypoint.sh` look like? How are you building your image? Update the question with additional information; don't post it as comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated in the question.